# Difference between let and var in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was going through the javascript style guide by Airbnb (https://github.com/airbnb/javascript).

In section 2.2 it is explained that

let is block-scoped rather than function-scoped like var.

```
// bad
var count = 1;
if (true) {
  count += 1;
}

// good, use the let.
let count = 1;
if (true) {
  count += 1;
}
```

I didn't get why the first one is bad practise and second is bad and if both let and var are block scoped then what difference does it make, if I use either of them?

Also what is the difference between function scoped and block scoped?

Comment: Seem a error to me. var and let should be in the if to make sense.

Comment: Probably a duplicate. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/1715004

Comment: "if both let and var are block scoped" — They aren't, that's the entire point.

Comment: That guide seems to be saying it is never okay to use var.

Comment: I think you just misunderstood what "let is block-scoped rather than function-scoped like var" means. A clearer wording would be "let is block-scoped, rather var which is function-scoped."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When something is block scoped it means that you can control the lifetime better and more intutive ways

for example

```
function a() {
    if (true) {
        var a = 7;
        let b = 42;
    }
}
```

The var a is pulled out in the scope of the function, rather than stying isolated in the block for the if, so like this;

```
function a() {
    var a;  // The JS compiler pulls the var out to this level
    if (true) {
        a = 7;
        let b = 42; // but keeps the let in this block.
    }
}
```

.. and that is counter intuitive and sometimes lead to problems -- the `let` does not have that problem.

Comment: In the first example both a & b won't be visible outside the if block and in the second example, since you defined a outside if so it will be visible. Still, didn't understood the difference between function and block scoped

Comment: The answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword) are very good -- have a look at those.